# Degeneracies in real systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there any theory/hypothesis that states that "Most real-world quantum systems have degeneracies?" What could be the basis of this statement?

Comment: What do you think? If you are quoting a source, please identify the source.

Comment: I don't know the source. I heard this in some discussion and have been thinking about it. Just wanted to check if people know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "degeneracy" means "degenerate energy levels" or degenerate eigenvalues. Then the question reduces to asking why many (most?) real-world systems have degenerate energy levels.

First, this seems a bit curious, because any random (according to a Gaussian distribution for example) Hamiltonian will not have any degeneracies. If you pick a random spectrum of bound states, it will not have degeneracies since the set of eigenvalues is measure countable and therefore measure zero.

So what could make real world systems special? The answer would be "symmetries". Given a symmetry of a system, the energy level is invariant under the symmetry (by definition), but the eigenstate does not need to be.

An example: Imagine a lattice Hamiltonian with translational invariance. Given an eigenvalue, if you can find only one eigenstate that is not translational invariant, you immediately have degeneracy: Any translation of this state must be an eigenstate too.

So it boils down to this question: Do most real-world quantum systems have symmetries (if you avoid imperfections I guess they have) and can you find eigenstates that do not exhibit these symmeries (often, the ground state will invariant under the symmetry because it'll be unique, but excited states not so much)?